# i want to send an email to user when user entered wrong password using javascript / java in html

Tags: javascript, java, html, email

i want to send an mail to user when he entered wrong password for two times to set an other password using java / java script . i have tried this using the java and html 
code is here help me out to do this

```js
  
//here how to add the function to send mail when user entered wrong password for two times. or redirect to java class file to send mail.//

function validation(){
        var uname=document.ulogin.username.value;
        var pass=document.ulogin.password.value;
        
        if(uname===0){
            alert("Enter username");
            document.ulogin.username.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(pass===0){
            alert("Enter password");
            document.ulogin.password.focus();
            return false;
        }
  var uword = hex_md5(document.getElementById(jfldid).value);

  if (uword==cword[anum-1]) {
  return true;
    }  
 //here how to add the function to send mail when user entered wrong password for two times. or redirect to java class file to send mail.//
```

```css
java for sending mail to user
package pack;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;  
import java.util.Properties;  
import java.util.logging.Level;  
import java.util.logging.Logger;  
import javax.mail.Authenticator;  
import javax.mail.Message;  
import javax.mail.MessagingException;  
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;  
import javax.mail.Session;  
import javax.mail.Transport;  
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;  
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;  
  
public class MailUtil {  
  
    private String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";  
    private String FROM_ADDRESS = "musicdonz@gmail.com";  
    private String PASSWORD = "password123";  
    private String FROM_NAME = "Alert";  
  
    public boolean sendMail(String[] recipients, String[] bccRecipients, String subject, String message) {  
        try {  
            Properties props = new Properties(); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);  
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.debug", "false");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");  
  
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new SocialAuth());  
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);  
  
            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(FROM_ADDRESS, FROM_NAME);  
            msg.setFrom(from);  
  
            InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];  
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {  
                toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);  
            }  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);  
  
  
            InternetAddress[] bccAddresses = new InternetAddress[bccRecipients.length];  
            for (int j = 0; j < bccRecipients.length; j++) {  
                bccAddresses[j] = new InternetAddress(bccRecipients[j]);  
            }  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddresses);  
  
            msg.setSubject(subject);  
            msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");  
            Transport.send(msg);  
            return true;  
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            return false;  
  
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            return false;  
        }  
    }  
  
    class SocialAuth extends Authenticator {  
  
        @Override  
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
  
            return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM_ADDRESS, PASSWORD);  
  
        }  
    }  
}
```

```html
<form action="userid" name="name" onsubmit="return validation()">
            <font style="color: black;font-size: 15px"> Enter UserName:</font><br></br>
                <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Enter username"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"> </input><br></br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: yellowgreen;color: #ffffff;width: 70px;"></input><span>  </span>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" style="background-color: tomato;color: #ffffff;width: 70px;"></input><br></br>
         New User <a href="register.jsp" style="color: cadetblue;font-size: 15px;">Register here</a> 
        </form>
```

Comment: You are missing a specific problem statement regarding the code shown. We don't know what is or isn't working or what errors might be being logged or what behavior needs to be changed